# Custom session keys in Chainspec for Mainnet config

Tags: babe, aura, substrate-node, session, accountid

I've seen some Substrate repo's where the `SessionKeys` (Aura, Babe, Grandpa, etc) are used with `unchecked_into()` .While the `stash/controller` keys are only used with `into()`.
These are some examples:

- Substrate: [Link](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L90)
- EdgeWare: [Link](https://github.com/edgeware-network/edgeware-node/blob/master/node/cli/src/mainnet_fixtures.rs#L256)
- ChainX: [Link](https://github.com/chainx-org/ChainX/blob/develop-2022/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L280)

Can someone please explain the actual reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 2):

Because `AccountId` was implemented `From<[u8; 32]>`. And the `KeyId`(aura, babe, grandpa...) was implemented `UncheckedFrom<[u8; 32]>` instead of `From<[u8; 32]>`.

Read more: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_core/crypto/trait.UncheckedFrom.html

Comment: But, is there a specific reason behind these implementations? like, why isn't `From<[u8; 32]>` is implemented for `KeyId`?

Comment: I think there is no specific reason. Those key types are generated by the macro. Maybe they want to make the macro more generic. And chose not to provide an infallible method.